# Error running DB2MOVE command

Tags: db2

I'm trying to execute the `DB2MOVE` command at a db2 prompt console in a windows 7 machine (I have db2 client installed, with proper catalogs and nodes created and tested.).

The steps I made was:

- Open the console (cmd)
- Run the `db2cmd` command (it is on path) and it opens a new console window
- Run the db2 tool which puts me into the db2 console window
- Connect to a existent database: `connect to mydb user x using x`
- Try to run the `db2move` command

```
db2move MYDB COPY -sn MYSCHEMA -tf C:/Users/MYUSER/Desktop/exp.lst -co 
  TARGET_DB TESTDB USER user USING pass SCHEMA_MAP ((MYSCHEMA, MYSCHEMA_TEST)) PARALLEL 2
```

ps.: there is no enter on the command line

The error I'm getting is:

> DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
>   valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
>   SQL0104N  An unexpected token "db2move MYDB COPY -sn" was found following
>   "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "".
>   SQLSTATE=42601
>   db2 =>

I'm strictly following the rules on the [docs](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002079.html?lang=en) what am I missing?

Comment: `db2move` is an OS command, not the CLP command. You run it in the `db2cmd` window.

Comment: @mustaccio `'db2move' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` Do I need to install anything in specific other than the client?

Comment: If I remember correctly, `db2move` is part of the server installation, it may not be available if you only install a client.

Comment: @mustaccio You are right I just logged into our server (linux) and could confirm your statement it is available at the server. I will try to run my command there to see what happens. You should add this last comment as an answer since it is the real problem here. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

In order to get the DB2 command window (DB2 CLP) in Windows, you can either Windows key + R and type db2cmd or Start > All Programs > IBM DB2 DB2COPY1 > DB2 Command Line Processor and then you can execute different db2 commands, like.

db2ilist    --> List instances
db2level    --> DB2 Version
db2licm -A  --> DB2 License

etc.

Regards,